# I need to check if a number is not a decimal, I'm trying with Number.isInteger() but doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I want a prompt alert keep popping out until the user enters a number with no decimals, and for some reason, I don't understand Number.isInteger is not working, for example it accepts 4.4 or 8.333... Is it that Number.isInteger evaluate to true with decimals?

check this snippet:

```js
function till() {
  let x = prompt("ingrese numero")
  if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(x)) === false) {
    till()
  }
}

till()

console.log("FInally out!")
```

Comment: integers  or float numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `parseInt` function just converts x to a `Integer` thus even you enter 8.333 it is taken as 8.

Here is a simple solution to your problem!

```js
function till() {
  let x = prompt("ingrese numero")
  if (parseInt(x) != parseFloat(x)) {
    till()
  }
}

till()

console.log("FInally out!")
```